# Twisted Documentation

Tags: python, twisted

From examples I've seen it seems that twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory Class has `clients` attribute but there is no such thing in the documntation http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory.html
In the documentation there are only classes and methods and no attributes.
So is the documentation not complete or something? Where should I look for the attributes of the classes?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such attribute maintained by `ServerFactory`.

Comment: http://radar.oreilly.com/2013/04/twisted-python-the-engine-of-your-internet.html
Please check out this example.It uses `self.transport.write(data)`
from Protocol Class, and I don't see such attribute in the documentation.